# Changing Textbox text on checking checkbox in gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have created a grid view in which there are certain number of rows of text box and checkbox. Now i want on checking the checkbox the text of textbox should be changed from 'A' to 'P'.
This is my design View.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" style="Text-align:center;">
<Columns>
<asp:TemplateField>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="grdData_SelectedIndexChanged"/>
</ItemTemplate>
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" OnClick="CheckAllEmp(this)"/>
</HeaderTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField>
<HeaderTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Status_Header" runat="server" Text="Status" />
</HeaderTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="a"></asp:TextBox>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

This is my Code Behind

```
protected void chkview_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
for (int i = 0; i < grdData.Rows.Count; i++){
CheckBox ck =(CheckBox)grdData.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1");
Label Child_Label =(Label)grdData.Rows[i].Cells[5].FindControl("Child_Label");

if (ck.Checked == true){
Child_Label.Text = "Present";}
else
Child_Label.Text = "Absent";}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code and use client site event `onclick` instead of `OnCheckedChanged` for your Checkbox and add one property `ClientIDMode="Static"` for textbox `TextBox1`.

**GrigView Markup:**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" Style="Text-align: center;">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="changeTextValue(this);" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" OnClick="CheckAllEmp(this)" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <HeaderTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Status_Header" runat="server" Text="Status" />
                    </HeaderTemplate>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="a" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

**JavaScript Function:**

```
<script>
    function changeTextValue(chk) {
        var currentTextID = $(chk).parents('tr').find('input[type="text"][id$="TextBox1"]');
        alert(chk.checked);
        if (chk.checked == true)
            currentTextID.val("Present");
        else
            currentTextID.val("Absent");
    }
</script>
```

Make sure to link jQuery file on your page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is working, but when i click on checkbox tick remain there for milliseconds only and value of textbox again changes to its original value

Comment: Do you refreshing your page every second using setinterval method in javascript?

Comment: I was made your changes 1 hour ago and still my changes on the page. http://i296.photobucket.com/albums/mm190/dexxterity/2015-03-28%2013_18_16-Mozilla%20Firefox_zpsz9vbap76.png. I think you have some problem in your other code.

Comment: When I am removing Autopostback = true, its working.

Comment: Cool...It was already removed from my answer, you have to just copy/paste. BTW your issue resolved. :)

Comment: If i want to insert this data into database what should i do ?

Comment: Do you want to save data on button click event?? if yeas follow this link, http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/316236/How-to-find-control-of-gridview-in-button-event

Comment: Yes, I want to insert on button click.
Value in my textbox is int type so its giving error cant convert data to int

Comment: Which control data you want to convert in int?

Comment: Value which is written in Textbox

Comment: "Present" and "Absent" is string value, you can't convert it to integer. You can use "1" for Present and "0" for Absent for textbox values and then save those values in your database. got?

Comment: foreach (GridViewRow g1 in grdData.Rows){ string Status = (g1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox).Text; 
string Status = (g1.FindControl("TextBox1") as TextBox).Text; 
SqlConnection con = newSqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Real_Attendance"].ConnectionString);
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Attendanc values('" + g1.Cells[3].Text + "','" + Status + "','" + Session["Time_Value"].ToString() + "','" + Session["Date_Value"].ToString() + "','" + Session["Sub_id"].ToString() + "')", con);
THIS is my button click event, Value of Status is not Inserting in Database.

Comment: Please mention "Attendanc" table columns in your query like: insert into Attendanc (column1, column2,...) values (value1, value2,...)

Comment: The main problem i am facing here is in database it is saving the default value of textbox(for example- if i have given text="Ab" then it is storing Ab only) after checking checkbox value is changing to present but in database, Ab is going

Comment: I solved your problem. I replied you on your other post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29377837/value-insertion-in-database-from-gridview/29386141#29386141

Comment: hi Dexterity 
Thanks for your previous Solution.
In the same code i inserted header checkbox now i want on checking that checkbox the value of label should be changed to Present.

Answer (score 0):

Add `AutoPostback="True"` to checkbox

and cs function:

```
protected void chkview_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Checkbox chk = (CheckBox)sender;
    GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)chk.NamingContainer;
    Label Child_Label =(Label)row.FindControl("Child_Label");
    if(chk.Checked)
       Child_Label.Text = "P";
    else
       Child_Label.Text = "A";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but value of textbox is not changing.