# Value insertion in database from GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have one column of `TextBox` and one column of `CheckBox` in `ItemTemplate` in a GridView and number of rows are generating dynamically.

When I click on `CheckBox` the value of `TextBox` is changing but when I am inserting the values into database, default value which I have given in `TextBox` it is saving that.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdData" runat="server" Style="text-align: center;">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onclick="changeTextValue(this)" />
            </ItemTemplate>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <!-- <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server"OnClick="CheckAllEmp(this)" />-->
            </HeaderTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="Status_Header" runat="server" Text="Status" />
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text="1" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found solution, remove `Enabled="false"` property from `TextBox1` and check.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Enabled="false" Text=1 ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:TextBox>
```

If you want to disabled textbox from end user, I suggest you to use **LABEL** control instead of **TEXTBOX**.

Here is the jQuery function for LABEL control.

```
<script>
function changeTextValue(chk) {
        var currentTextID = $(chk).parents('tr').find('span[id$="Label1"]');
        alert(chk.checked + ": " + currentTextID.text());
        if (chk.checked == true)
            currentTextID.text("Present");
        else
            currentTextID.text("Absent");
    }
 </script>
```

**Label control should be like below:**

```
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Absent" EnableViewState="false" ClientIDMode="Static"></asp:Label>
```

Please let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Did you changed your Textbox control with Label control??

Comment: YES i changed my Textbox field with Label